# A problem while operating HYPODD program

Tags: fortune

I use HypooDD to relocate earthquakes but when I type on the terminal:

```
hypoDD hypoDD.inp
```

this error appears:

```
STOP >>> Increase MAXEVE in hypoDD.inc. statement executed
```

I changed the MAXEVE in the hypoDD.inc file but the error still appear. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: increase `MAXEVE` even more? What's `MAXEVE` for? Maybe you have a loop or a recursion that produces "too much" EVEnts?

Comment: MAXEVE is the Maximum number of events (must be at least the size of the number of earthquakes listed in the event file. I increased it in the mentioned file but it still give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with me when I did the following:
1.change the dimensions in the hpoDD.inc file.
2. recompile the program using the "make" command.